# Why Retrofit waits till timeout to give onFailure call back if internet is not available?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 to make API calls in my Android application. I am creating a Retrofit client in the following way.

```
if (retrofitClient == null) {
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

    val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(API_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(API_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    retrofitClient = retrofitBuilder.client(okHttpClientBuilder.build()).build()
}

val call = retrofitClient?.create(ApiService::class.java)?.getMovies()
call?.enqueue(object : Callback<MoviesResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<MoviesResponse>, response: Response<MoviesResponse>) {
        //Handle Success
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        //Handle failure
    }
})
```

Here If the internet connection is not available while making the first call(when retrofitClient is just created), I get the onFailure callback immediately. But if the internet connection was present for the first call and is not available for the second API call(I am reusing retrofitClient for second API call), the onFailure will be called after the time-out with java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

Any comments on why onFailure callback is delayed till time out?

I am getting this issue in Android emulators running in API level 21 and above. Here, internet connection was turned on by enabling emulator data keeping wifi off.

I have tested in few devices like Samsung S8, Samsung Note 8, Mi A1, Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 and a Sony Ericsson phone(running in 4.1.2) and the issue is not reproducible in all these devices. I believe there might be few devices where this issue will be reproducible as it is always reproducible in the emulator.

Here if I don’t reuse retrofitClient, the issue is not present. So I would also like to know whether it is good to reuse the retrofitClient.

Thanks in advance :)